# AIS Data Transformed or CVS Format

Tags: ais

I am looking for AIS Shipping Route Data. I have not had much luck finding it in either SHP format or even in CVS format does anyone have a real good source of finding this type of data? To add to my problems I need only a specific area of coverage? It is starting to look like I may need to purchase the Data.

Comment: That is correct; the USPS AIS DB is commercial/copyrighted product from the USPS. It is a TXT based file that you would need to parse into a CSV format to extract to a usable form.

Comment: So it is a product that I would need to purchase directly from a provider then?? I am asking the specifics for a project that I am on. Thank You

Comment: Yes, you can get the information on the product and licensing from here... https://www.usps.com/business/address-information-systems.htm I use it heavily in my state to fill in addressing formation where no other sources are available.

Comment: What is your area of interest? Maybe by chance... ftp://ftp.csc.noaa.gov/temp/MarineCadastre/For_CSC/